# Expect Interact and special characters

Tags: macros, tcl, expect, cisco

trying to create a macro program with expect to help me manage my cisco devices>

I want to keep all native cisco functions like tab complete ETC.

initially I wanted to type "!...!" where my macro is inside the bangs, my code looked like this:

```
interact {
    -re "!(.+)!" { #find correct macro }
}
```

but with this method, there is no feedback to the user. what happens if they misspell? etc then they can't see their corrections with backspace.

then I started thinking about just capturing each character press and building a string

```
interact {
        #book says backspace character
        "\b" {
                set command [lreplace $command end end]
        }
        #detect return, sending command
        -re "\r" {
                set command [join $command ""]
                if [regexp "^!" $command] {
                        #send ctrl+u to erase line sent
                        send "\025"
                        findMacro $command
                }
                set command ""
                send "\r"
        }
        #send tab for tab completion
        "\t" { send "\t" }
        -re "(.)" {
                send $interact_out(1,string)
                lappend command $interact_out(1,string)
        }
}
```

but I can't "expect" the backspace. I've tried 0x08.. etc nothing is working. in the end I'm not even sure this is the way to go simply because there are to many other buttons a user could push and mess up my string I'm building.

the real solution, I think, is to wait until "\r" is pressed, and then run a regex on that line. but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Are you intend to make these interactions between a spawned telnet process ?

Comment: well, ssh, but looks like I'm going to use the `expect_user` command and parse the string from there.

I'm actually running into issues though where my procedure isn't allowing the interact to work. If I comment out the procedure interact works as expected. if I leave it as a normal procedure my expect times out